# Why is sigwait() MT-safe but sigsuspend() is not?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm looking to write a multithreaded application where one thread waits for another to signal it before continuing.  According to [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigsuspend.html), `sigsuspend` is not MT-safe because of a race condition.  According to [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3174/6j31do6ho/index.html), `sigwait` should be used in these cases.  I'm trying to understand why.

Based on the man page descriptions ([`sigwait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html) and [`sigsuspend`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html)), it appears that...

`sigsuspend (const sigset_t *mask)` actually changes the *process's* signal mask, which would affect all threads.

`sigwait (const sigset_t *set, int *sig)` just waits for one of the indicated signals in `set` *without* changing the thread's (or process's) signal mask.

Is this understanding correct? And if so, how does `sigwait` block without changing the signal mask?

Comment: Consider using condition variables instead of signals.

Comment: @abligh - Excellent advice, which I ended up taking.  Didn't even think about that - turned out to be a simple semaphore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually sigwait changes the mask but then restore it, see this (Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment): [Signals and Threads](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~ivana/courses/tos/sistemi_knjige/pomocno/apue/APUE/0201433079/ch12lev1sec8.html).

And also this: [Oracle Multithreaded Programming Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/gen-75415/index.html)

Comment: I actually own that book - didn't even think of checking it.